# Compare arraylist objects in java

Tags: java

I have list of objects in an arraylist and I need to compare every objects with other objects available in the arraylist;
For Example:

```
Class Employee {
    private String empname;
    private Long empid;
    private boolean empsex;

    public String getEmpname() {
        return empname;
    }
    public void setEmpname(String empname) {
        this.empname = empname;
    }
    public Long getEmpid() {
        return empid;
    }
    public void setEmpid(Long empid) {
        this.empid = empid;
    }
    public boolean isEmpsex() {
        return empsex;
    }
    public void setEmpsex(boolean empsex) {
        this.empsex = empsex;
    }
}

public list<Employee> getEmpList() {
    List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    Employee emp =  new Employee();
    for(...) {
        //insert values to emp object for n number of times;
    }
    empList.add(emp); //add emp.object to empList;
    return empList;
}
```

Now while inserting these values to UI; Need to compare objects in the list; where any two or more objects matches with each other or not?

Comment: Implement `Comparable` interface.

Comment: As I understand ,u need to compare Objects in two lists but do what with it?After u finish comparing u need list of those objects .Please elaborate

Comment: I tried implementing the Comparable<Employee> but it gives implements only CompareTo method and it doesn't solve the purpose!

Comment: What did you write under the `compareTo` method?

Comment: @AbhinavKumar To check for duplicates and similar values; For an Unique ID, the name and emp-sex can be the same; Just have to loop through all the objects and return msg if its match;

Comment: Basically u want a list of Objects which are present in both the list?Right?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption that you want to eliminate the duplicates from the list and do not show duplicates on GUI.

Use [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) collection, it automatically takes care of duplicates.

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets
>   contain no pair of elements `e1` and `e2` such that `e1.equals(e2)`, and at
>   most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models
>   the mathematical set abstraction.

Override `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods.

References:

- [On equals and hashcode in Java](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074996/hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java-object---a-pragmatic-concept.html)
- [Overriding equals and hashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You could override equals method for that class to compare the objects of the same class the way you want.

**Default equals method:**

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String) anObject;
        int n = value.length;
        if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                        return false;
                i++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Link about overriding equals:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-write-equals-method-in-java.html

Answer (score 0):

One simple method of doing this is to just do a double for loop.

```
public static List<Employee> getList(List<Employee> oldList)
{
    List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    for (int i = 0; i < oldList.size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < oldList.size; j++)
        {
            //compare oldList.get(i) with oldList.get(j)
            //if match, set some boolean
        }
    //if duplicate found, delete one copy, or add one to new list, etc
    }
```

This allows you to go through each element in the outer loop, and compare to every other element in the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

I guess employee id (`empid`) is unique for each emplyee, yes?

If so, use a hash instead where empid is the key and employee object is the value.

```
Map<Long, Employee> empmap = new HashMap<Long, Employee>();
empmap.put(currentEmployee.getEmpid(), currentEmployee)
```

Comment: For those unique ID's; How to check Employee object like name and emp-sex are same? Having two loops?

Comment: @JohnSmith Why would you compare those? You could have two different employees with the same name. No, make sure you have one unique identifier and compare with that only.